# Access a service in AngularUI Router onEnter callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im using Angular 1.5.6 and am using AngularUI Router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I have different routes e.g. customer and users. In each of these there are different 'sub-roots' e.g. one for list and one for edt. Im setting up the customer route here:

```
import customerListModule from './list/customer.list';
import customerServiceModule from './services/customer.service';
...
...

function customerModule($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('/customer', ['$state', function($state) {
            $state.go('customer.list.tracked');
        }]);

    $stateProvider
        .state('customer', {
            parent: 'root',
            url: '/customer',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'root@app': {
                    template: '<div class="customer" ui-view=""></div>'
                }
            },
            onEnter: () => {
                // in here I want to change my customer servce
            },
        })
        .state('customer.list', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                '@customer': {
                    template: '<customer></customer>'
                }
            },
            breadcrumbs: {
                name: 'customer.breadcrumbs.list'
            },
            params: {
                saving: false
            }
        })
        .state('customer.edit', {
            parent: 'customer.list',
            url: '/:id/edit',
            views: {
                '@customer': {
                    template: editTemplate(),
                    controller: manageCustomerCtrl,
                    controllerAs: 'manageCustomerVM'
                }
            },
            breadcrumbs: {
                name: 'customer.breadcrumbs.edit'
            },
            resolve: {
                isAuthorized: 'readWriteAccess'
            },
            bodyClass: 'product-form'
        });
}

export default angular.module('customerAdminUI.customer', [
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.router',
        customerListModule.name,
        customerServiceModule.name,
        ...
        ...
    ])
    .config(customerModule);
```

I have a customer service which I want to access in the onEnter callback of the customer state. I tried to inject it into the customerModule method so that I can use it in the onEnter() callback:

```
function customerModule($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, CustomerService) {

    ...
    ...


    $stateProvider
        .state('customer', {
            parent: 'root',
            url: '/customer',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'root@app': {
                    template: '<div class="customer" ui-view=""></div>'
                }
            },
            onEnter: () => {
                CustomerService.clearSearch();
            },
        })
```

However I get the error:

```
Unknown provider: CustomerService
```

How can I use a service in the onEnter callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ask for a service as a param

```
// not ready for minification
onEnter: function(CustomerService) {
   CustomerService.dowhatneeded...
},

// preferred way
onEnter: ['CustomerService', function(service) {
   service.dowhatneeded...
}],
```